# undefined index when trying to display number from database

Tags: php

i am trying to display the isbn number from my database when they click an image from another page and for some reason i keep getting this error

Notice: Undefined index: isbn on line 8

```
            <html><title>Employee List</title>  <head></head>
            <body>
            <h1> List of Employees </h1>
            <?php
            require_once("include/db_connect.php");
            $db_link = db_connect("project");

            $isbn = $_REQUEST['isbn'];

            $query = "SELECT * FROM bookstore WHERE isbn = '$isbn'";

            $result = mysql_query($query);

                    if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                     $isbn = $row['isbn'];

                    echo "<tr><td><strong>Isbn:</strong>". $isbn. "</td>";

            }

            ?>
            </body>
            </html>
```

main program for my php program

```
            <?php require_once("include/db_connect.php"); ?>
            <html>
            <head><title>Displaying Image files using PHP</title></head>
            <body>
            <h1>Bookworms Booksite</h1>

                    <style> @import "css/style.css";</style>


                <div id = "nav">
                        <ul>
                        <li><a class = "navbutton" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a class = "navbutton" href="membership.html">Books</a></li>
                        <li><a class = "navbutton" href="classes.html">Shopping Cart</a></li>
                        <li><a class = "navbutton" href="">Checkout</a></li>
                        <li><a class = "navbutton" href="shop.html" id ="current" >About</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <p></p>
                    <p></p>

                 <div id = "sideNav">
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href="#home">Enter Bookstore</a></li><br>
                    <li><a href="#news">Bookstore Administartion</a></li><br>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Search</a></li>
                    </ul>
                 </div>


                            <?php


                            $db_link = db_connect("project");

                            // Retrieve table properties

                            $fields = mysql_list_fields("project", "bookstore");
                            $num_columns = mysql_num_fields($fields);

                            // Make a simple database query to select all columns and rows

                            $query = "SELECT * FROM bookstore";
                            $result = mysql_query($query) or die("SQL query failed");

                            // Display results as an HTML table. Note how mysql_field name
                            // uses the $fields object to extract the column names

                            echo '<table border="1" cellpadding = "5" >';

                            // Display the column names

                            echo "<tr>";



                            echo "</tr>";

                            // Loop over the rows of the table.
                            // $row contains the information for each row
                            // Refer to the names of the fields in the table
                            // Must ahow the path where the image files are held

                            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                            {
                               echo "<tr>";
                               $isbn = $row['isbn'];
                               $title = $row['title'];

                               echo "<td><a href='bookDetail.php'><img src = 'images/". $row['image']. "'></a></td>";
                               echo "<a href='bookDetail.php? id= ". $isbn . "'>". $title . "</a><br/>";
                                                  echo "<td>". $row['isbn']."</td>";

                               echo "<td>". $row['title']."</td>";
                               echo "<td>". $row['author']."</td>";
                               echo "<td>". $row['pub']."</td>";
                               echo "<td>". $row['year']."</td>";
                               echo "<td>". $row['price']."</td>";


                               echo "</tr>";

                            }
                            echo "</table>";

                            // Free the resources and close the connection

                            mysql_free_result($result);
                            mysql_close($db_link);
                            ?>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Show us the table structure of `bookstore` (`DESCRIBE bookstore`)

Comment: http://gyazo.com/e61170bd9467f124bc0c37d8c879516d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 8 is this :

```
$isbn = $_REQUEST['isbn'];
```

Therefore, your $_REQUEST['isbn'] variable is undefined. Do a print_r ($_REQUEST); to check your request parameters.

To use $_REQUEST['isbn'], you need the page to be called by a form and have a field with name='isbn', otherwise it won't exist.

More information about forms : http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: it says this now Array ( [id] => 0-12-066190-2 )

Comment: Yes, meaning your form isn't passing the 'isbn' parameter to the page. So you can't obtain it to put it in your query. We need the rest of your code to help more.

Comment: To get the $_REQUEST['isbn'] variable, you need to have a field within a form in the caller page that has name='isbn'. The code you're showing has no form.

Answer (score -1):

Actually the line 8 is "$_REQUEST['isbn'];" which has nothing to do with database. Are you sure you're passing the parameter to the page?